# Чтение информации из радиомодуля

Tags: android, android-ndk

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно добраться до радиомодуля? Мне нужна информация о мощности базовой станции, частоте, на которой она работает и т.д., т.е. низкоуровневая информация, к которой нет доступа в стандартной Android SDK.

Comment: AT-команды ее, наверное, тоже не предоставляют?

Comment: Нет, у AT-команд нет обширного функционала.

Comment: А хоть какой-то софт, реализующий нужный функционал существует?

Comment: Теоретический вендоры (создатели радиомодуля) имеют полный доступ к нему.